# is there a way to use Laravel sanctum token to be able to access protected routes (Laravel Project)

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-sanctum

I'm building a website witch has some protected routes that I want to prevent non-authenticated users from accessing it, So I'm using Laravel Sanctum for that purpose. I was testing this using postman, but now I want to actually use it in production from backend, So how I suppose to do that token that was generated after login!

Thanks in advance.

[image: This is the protected routes from my web.php file]

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is late, but it may be useful to someone else

You will set your login routes

```
// Login Route
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/login', LoginAction::class)->name('auth.login');
    });

// Logout Route
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/logout', LogoutAction::class)->name('auth.logout');
    });
```

```
public function __invoke(AuthRequest $request)
  {
    $username = $request->input('username');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $remember = $request->input('remember');

// I use filter_var to know username is email or just the regular username
    $field = filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';

// User::where('username', $username)->first();
// User::where('email', $username)->first();
    $user = User::where($field, $username)->first();

if (
      !$user || !Hash::check($password, $user->password)
      || !Auth::attempt(
        [
          $field => $username,
          'password' => $password
        ],
        $remember
      )
    ) {
// Return Error Message
      return $this->error(['message' => trans('auth.failed')], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

// After Check Useranme And Password Create Token
$token = $user->createToken($request->device)->plainTextToken;

// Return Success Message With Token
return $this->success(['message' => trans('auth.login', ['user' => $user->username]), 'token' => $token, 'user' => $user]);
```

in vuex Actions

```
export const loginAction = ({ commit }, userInfo) => {
  let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    login(userInfo)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.success) {
          commit("SET_LOGIN_USER", response.payload.user);
// Set Token Mutaion
          commit("SET_TOKEN", response.payload.token);
         
          // Notify User for success logged in
          Notify.create({
            type: "positive",
            message: `welcome ${response.payload.user.username}`,
          });
// Redirect to dashboard
          router.push(
            urlParams.get("redirect") || { name: "dashboard" }
          );
        }

        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
// For any error remove any auth user details and notify him
        Notify.create({
          type: "negative",
          message: `${error.response?.data.payload}`,
        });
        commit("REMOVE_AUTH_DETAILS");
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

in vuex mutations 3 methods

```
// Helpers Fuctions
import { setLoginUser, setToken, removeToken, removeLoginUser } from '../../../utils/auth';

export const SET_LOGIN_USER = (state, user) => {
  state.loginUser = user
  setLoginUser(user)
}
export const SET_TOKEN = (state, token) => {
  state.token = token
  setToken(token)
}

export const REMOVE_AUTH_DETAILS = (state) => {
  state.loginUser = null
  state.token = null
  removeLoginUser()
  removeToken()
}
```

My Helper Functions

```
// I use Quasar Framework But you can use any cookie package like js-cookie
import { Cookies } from "quasar";

const TokenName = "TOKEN";
const LoginUser = "LOGIN_USER";

export function setToken(token) {
    return Cookies.set(TokenName, token);
}

export function getToken() {
    return Cookies.get(TokenName);
}

export function removeToken() {
    return Cookies.remove(TokenName);
}

export function setLoginUser(loginUser) {
    return Cookies.set(LoginUser, JSON.stringify(loginUser));
}

export function getLoginUser() {
    return Cookies.get(LoginUser);
}

export function removeLoginUser() {
    return Cookies.remove(LoginUser);
}
```

I use Vue js for frontend and axios for making requests
in axios file request.js

```
// It's helper function to get token from cookie
import { getToken } from "./auth";

import router from "../router";
import store from "../store";

import axios from "axios";

// Create axios instance
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: "/api/v1/",
  timeout: 10000 // Request timeout
});

// Request intercepter
service.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    if (getToken()) {
      config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + getToken(); // Set Token
    }
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    // Do something with request error
    console.log("error-axios", error); // for debug
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// response pre-processing
service.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response.data;
  },
  error => {
    // remove auth user informations from cookies and return to login page if unauthorized

    if ([401].includes(error.response.status)) {
      store.commit('auth/REMOVE_AUTH_DETAILS')
      router.push({ name: "login" });
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default service;
```

// Logout Fuction in controller or action

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
  {
    if(! $request->user()) {
      return $this->error(['message' => trans('auth.no_auth_user')]);
    }
// Remove Token
    $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
    return $this->success([
      'message' => trans('auth.logout', ['user' => auth()->user()->username])
    ], Response::HTTP_OK);
  }
```

// Logout mutation (vuex)

```
export const logoutAction = ({ commit }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    logout()
      .then(() => {
        Notify.create({
          type: "negative",
          message: `see you later ${getLoginUser().username}`,
        });
        commit("REMOVE_AUTH_DETAILS");
        router.push({ name: "login" });
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        router.push({ name: "login" });
        commit("REMOVE_AUTH_DETAILS");
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

Any other help I will not be late